# USB flash drive wont format

Tags: usb-flash-drive

Eh, I bought this USB flash drive  1 day ago to make a bootable USB flash drive for Ubuntu. After writing the iso a couple of times, I still can't boot the USB flash drive (maybe UEFI problem) but now this USB flash drive has problem itself.

When I connect, it says 'you need to format it...' but I can't format it, it shows error. I tried PartitionGuru tool and even that tool crashed and couldn't format it.

So my USB flash drive done :( ?

EDIT: It was a Kingston 8 GB USB flash drive but now it shows only 8 MB

Comment: It does sound like it has failed. Time to get the shop to swap it for another one, perhaps from a different manufacturer.

Comment: have you tried to delete or create a partition first

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't think that shopkeeper would change a $4 stick e.e but first I want to be completely sure if its dead or not

Comment: @Waleed If they get a lot of returned ones, they may stop selling them. I suggest using the refund to buy one from a more reputable manufacturer in the same shop - the shopkeeper is likely to be more amenable to that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton LOL! I exchnged it with another USB but with 4GB  and I tried to use UnetBootIn/UUI to make it bootable but now same thing happened. First it wont boot, second, it won't format. Should I exchange it again or this time its my fault?